# Django: Force uniqueness of many-to-many 'through' field

Tags: django, database, django-models

I am trying to design a database schema for a stock portfolio. What I have so far seems to work with one caveat --- a portfolio can contain two holdings of the same stock. I want a uniqueness of holdings with respect to the stock in the portfolio. I am new to Django, and haven't been able to figure it out.

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    """
    All available stocks
    """
    symbol = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=4)

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    """
    A user's portfolio containing stocks.
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usd = models.FloatField(default=0)
    stocks = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, blank=True, through='Holding')

class Holding(models.Model):
    """
    A holding of a stock in a portfolio.
    """
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For example, in the admin interface I can create a `Portfolio` and then a `Holding` with `amount=20` and `stock='ABC'`. I can duplicate that same holding, but I shouldn't be able to. The correct way would be to lookup the existing holding and add to `amount`.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got it...

Trick is to add `unique_together` in the intermediate table. It makes the stock unique in the portfolio.

```
class Holding(models.Model):
    """
    A holding of a stock in a portfolio.
    """
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('stock', 'portfolio'),]
```